# How to make user input unaffected by span elements color style

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have some words in a content editable `<div>` that needs to be a different color from the rest of the text. The problem is that I don't want the user to be able to use the different color style and they should still be able to delete the blue word.

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>Hello world<span style="color: blue">!</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible for the users' input to be unaffected by the color style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really provided enough for us to go on - eg. what are the rules which determine what is blue and what is not? Is the blue text always an exclamation mark? Does it always come at the end?

What it sounds like you will need is to build a simple lightweight code editor and apply the rules you desire. The way this works is you create a transparent editable div in the same space as a "display" div. The content of the editable textarea is invisible and the contents of the "display" div are visible. For every key stroke, you take the content of the editable textarea and write it to the "display" div and apply any custom rules. Here's a simple fiddle showing what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/ymdrfupb/1/

```
const editable = document.querySelector('.editor > [contenteditable]');
const display = document.querySelector('.editor > .display');

function setDisplayContent(text) {
  // wrap any non-alphanumeric trailing characters with a blue span
  display.innerHTML = text.replace(/([^\w]+)$/, '<span class="blue">$1</span>');
}

editable.addEventListener('input', (ev) => {
  setDisplayContent(ev.target.innerHTML);
});

setDisplayContent(editable.innerHTML);
```

Comment: The tricky thing is that you can't use regular expressions to detect where the word is located. I have some indexes to specific commas in a sentence, which should be colored blue. So i've made a system that incapsulates the word with a span element wich has the color style of blue.

Comment: I don't know what your rules are... that parts on you. The gist of my comment is, you need to create a custom editor and apply whatever crazy rules you can come up with. You will probably need to do a much more complex thing where you grab the currently typed character, figure out where the cursor is, and conditionally update the HTML content with whatever rules you can come up with. I will not write this editor for you ;)

Comment: That was also the conclusion i came to, was just hoping for a bit easier solution.. But i seriously appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Good luck on that one. Building an editor by hand is not really fun, especially if your language is not "regular" and easily tokenized. You might be able to use something like [nearly](https://nearley.js.org/) to help you, or at least help you in your search.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making the entire DIV editable, break it into separate spans, so you can specify the individual editability.

```html
<div id="textarea"><span contenteditable>Hello world</span><span style="color: blue">!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I still want the user to be able to delete the blue word. Sorry for being unclear